# Why is my JavaScript code giving giving a reference error when I have defined the property inside the object?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a beginner to javascript and learning about objects. When I run the initializeDeck method I get a reference error saying values/suits is not defined. However, I think I'm using the this keyword appropriately to access the objects properties. It would be immensely helpful if someone could explain this to me.

```
const myDeck = {
  deck : [],
  suits : ["hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs"],
  values : "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A",
  
  initializeDeck : function() {
    this.values = values;
    this.suits = suits;
}}
console.log(myDeck.initializeDeck());
```

Comment: Well, the *variable* `values` does in fact not exist. A property named `myDeck.values` does though…

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here: yes, the `this.values` and `this.suits` will return values, but `values` and `suits` on the other hand are undefined variables.

Comment: `this.values` is `already` the object's values. Instead of `this.values = values` write `console.log(this.values)` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not `this.values`. It is `values`.
`this.values` can be accessed inside the method. `this` means the object `myDeck` here.

Even if you do:

```
const myDeck = {
  deck : [],
  suits : ["hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs"],
  values : "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A",
  initializeDeck : function() {
    this.values = values;
    this.suits = suits;
}
}
console.log(values); //You will get an error here. values is not defined.
```

By the way you need not initialize. You are not using a constructor and this is a simple object literal. You can simply use `myDeck.values` outside.

Answer (score 2):

Your function **initializeDeck** should take some parameters like **values** and **suits**. Above you are calling a function without arguments and trying to set some fields to non existing local variables.

Instead try this

```
const myDeck = {
  deck : [],
  suits : ["hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs"],
  values : "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A",
  
  initializeDeck : function(values, suits) {
    this.values = values;
    this.suits = suits;
}}
console.log(myDeck.initializeDeck(<someValues>, <someSuits>));
```

Comment: Shouldn't `suit` and `values`  therefor be variables _outside_ of the object? At the moment you still have them as object properties.

Comment: Depends on what he wants to do, my provided function updates the objects fields with given arguments.

Answer (score 1):

As you learn more about JavaScript you'll discover [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) which you might find more intuitive. Similar to  mfurkangok's answer where you pass in your suits/values to `initialiseDeck`, here you pass in the suits/values when you create a new *instance* of Deck.

In my example `initialise` builds the deck from the suits/values, and `showDeck` logs the deck array to the console.

```js
class Deck {

  constructor(values, suits) {
    this.values = values;
    this.suits = suits;
    this.deck = [];
  }

  initialiseDeck() {
    for (let s = 0; s < this.suits.length; s++) {
      for (let v = 0; v < this.values.length; v++) {
        this.deck.push(`${this.suits[s]} ${this.values[v]}`);
      }
    }
    return this;
  }

  showDeck() {
    console.log(this.deck);
  }

}

const values = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A'];
const suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'spades', 'clubs'];

const myDeck = new Deck(values, suits);

myDeck.initialiseDeck().showDeck();
```